# Provide a business network archive (.bna) file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Can anyone please provide a link for a sample business network archive `(.bna)` file for demo and testing purpose on hyperledger composer-playground. I'm not getting one on any other websites.

I am stuck with my business network, trying to create a demo for cryptocurrency of my own.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate your own business network archive. As you know the business network consists of various files in composer, such as

- the model definition
- the logic javascript file
- the permissions file
- optionally, the query description file

When going through the tutorial, you will notice that there is one step where you generate the `.bna` file from these assets.

```
composer archive create -t dir -n . -a sample-network@0.0.1.bna
```

What this does is it creates your `.bna` file from the assets in the current directory. *(In fact, the file is just a zip file of these assets, including `package.json` etc.)*

To understand the options here is the output of `composer create archive create help`

> composer archive create --archiveFile digitialPropertyNetwork.zip
>   --sourceType module --sourceName digitalproperty-network
>
> Options:
>   --help             Show help  [boolean]
>   -v, --version    Show version number  [boolean]
>   --archiveFile, -a  Business network archive file name. Default is based on the Identifier of the BusinessNetwork  [string]
>   --sourceType, -t   The type of the input containing the files used to create the archive  [required] [choices: "module", "dir"]
>   --sourceName, -n   The Location to create the archive from e.g. NPM module directory or Name of the npm module to use  [required]

When you have a network running, you can use `composer network download` to generate the archive file (use the help flag to learn more).

You will find sample setups in the public [playground space](http://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/). You can export the files with the "Export" button on the left.

Comment: Thanks for such an explanatory answer. But as I said,  I was just asking if I can get any .bna files created for some specific task or some system. The Business Network Definition Templates given in composer playground are just some vague and more generalized templates..

Comment: No, they are for specific tasks. Look more carefully.

Comment: Also, if you want to copy .bna files from existing projects, there are dozens of them on GitHub. Just search for ".bna".

Comment: I was also able to find couple of `.bna` files here:

https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/blockchain-samples/tree/master/samples/composer

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial [Playground Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/playground-tutorial) takes you through creating a Business Network, and at the end you could create a .BNA by exporting the current Network.

If you want an immediate sample, then at the start of that tutorial don't use an empty network, select one of the Templates provided.  Should you need a .BNA file then again you can export it.

Comment: @R Thatcher: Yes that's right, but i wanted some completely built business network.